# Getting last product ID from cart even if it's already in card

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart

**What i need to do:** i'm making a custom widget to display a notice message every time user add an item to cart " You've added [item_name] to cart " dynamically. Here's what i did :

```
public function widget($args,$instance){
    if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_is_hidden', is_cart() || is_checkout() ) ) {
        return;
    } 

    $items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    $ids = array();

    foreach($items as $item => $values) { 

            $_product = $values['data']; 
            $ids[] = $_product->get_id(); 
    } 

    $last_product_id = end($ids); ?>

    <i class="last-item"> user added <?php echo wc_get_product( $last_product_id )->get_title(); ?> to cart. </i>
```

to make it dynamic every time user adds a new item in cart, i used ***woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments*** hook :

```
function cart_msg_refresh( $fragments ) {
  $fragments['.last-item'] = '<i class="last-item"> user added ' . wc_get_product( $last_product_id )->get_title() . ' to cart. </i>';
  return $fragments;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'cart_msg_refresh' );
```

So far, so good. This does work and i do get the message with last added to cart item's name.

**The issue:** Thing is, if user adds once again an item that is already in the cart, it will not show that item's ID. I did print_r() the array to troubleshoot the problem and saw that if the item is in cart, it will not add the ID and just increment the quantity of that item inside the items array of get_cart(). Thus explaining why i can't retrieve that product's ID.

**EDIT :**
For the first code with $last_product_id, i'm using a filter to 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments' in order dynamically show the message. And it does work, only thing is the message not displaying when item is already in cart ( due to ID issues mentioned before). Ajax would be the solution that would suit me, thanks to @LoicTheAztec for mentioning that.

Comment: Since WooCommerce 3, `$_product = $values['data']->post; $ids[] = $_product->ID;`  is replaced by `$_product = $values['data']; $ids[] = $_product->get_id();`… For info the filter hook "woocommerce_add_cart_item_data" only works for simple add to cart, but not for Ajax add to cart.

Comment: i'm using woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments hook so i would like it to stay dynamic by using the Ajax kind without reloading the page with a post. No plugins on. Post has been edited, thank you

Comment: This will not work on simple add to cart, only on ajax add to cart. So you should provide the related code that you where using to display a notice in your question

Comment: eddited post with full code used by widget method and woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments hook (this hook is using AJAX)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but it might help someone.

We had the same issue on our website. We were showing a notification when a user adds a product to cart. When a user adds Product A then Product B and then Product A once again to cart the last notification was showing Product B details since it is still the last item in the cart, while the quantity of the first item in cart is just incremented.

In the hook `woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments` you can make use of the `$_POST` which provides the last product id added. In your case it would be something like the below:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'cart_msg_refresh' );
function cart_msg_refresh( $fragments ) {
    $product_id = !empty($_POST['product_id']) ? $_POST['product_id'] : '';
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $title = method_exists($product, 'get_title') ? $product->get_title() ? '';
    $fragments['.last-item'] = '<i class="last-item"> user added ' . 
    $title . ' to cart. </i>';
    return $fragments;
}
```